# BizTalk adapter generate hierarchical schema

Tags: sql, wcf, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am trying to use BizTalk adapter (SQL or WCF-SQL) to create a multilevel hierarchical schema. My query is like this

```
SELECT
    CustomerQueueMessage.customer_queue_ID  AS CustomerQueueMsgID,
    CustomerMaster.customer_ID              AS [CustomerID],
    CustomerAddressType.address_type_ID     AS [AddressTypeID],         
    CustomerSalesRep.sales_rep_type_code    AS [SalesRepTypeCode]
 FROM CustomerQueue AS CustomerQueueMessage 
 INNER JOIN dbo.MDM_Customer                AS CustomerMaster       ON (CustomerQueueMessage.customer_queue_ID = CustomerMaster.customer_queue_ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.MDM_CustomerAddressType     AS CustomerAddressType  ON (CustomerAddressType.customer_queue_ID  = CustomerMaster.customer_queue_ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.MDM_CustomerSalesRep        AS CustomerSalesRep     ON (CustomerSalesRep.customer_queue_ID     = CustomerMaster.customer_queue_ID)
 FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, XMLDATA
```

When I generate the schema using SQL adapter I get this structure

[image]

what I want is

[image]

Table **CustomerSalesRep** is under **CustomerAddressType**. I want **CustomerSalesRep** to be at the same level with **CustomerAddressType**, both immediately under **CustomerMaster**.

If I remove the FOR XML statement and use WCF-SQL adapter to generate the schema, I get no hierarchy, all the columns are at the same level.

Any ideas? Preferably I would like to do it using WCF-SQL adapter, but also SQL would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
SELECT
    CustomerSalesRep.sales_rep_type_code    AS "CustomerQueueMessage/CustomerMaster/CustomerSalesRep/SalesRepTypeCode",
    CustomerAddressType.address_type_ID     AS "CustomerQueueMessage/CustomerMaster/CustomerAddressType/AddressTypeID",         
    CustomerMaster.customer_ID              AS "CustomerQueueMessage/CustomerMaster/CustomerID",
    CustomerQueueMessage.customer_queue_ID  AS "CustomerQueueMessage/CustomerQueueMsgID"
 FROM CustomerQueue AS CustomerQueueMessage 
 INNER JOIN dbo.MDM_Customer                AS CustomerMaster       ON (CustomerQueueMessage.customer_queue_ID = CustomerMaster.customer_queue_ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.MDM_CustomerAddressType     AS CustomerAddressType  ON (CustomerAddressType.customer_queue_ID  = CustomerMaster.customer_queue_ID)
 INNER JOIN dbo.MDM_CustomerSalesRep        AS CustomerSalesRep     ON (CustomerSalesRep.customer_queue_ID     = CustomerMaster.customer_queue_ID)
 FOR XML PATH('SAPcustom'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
```

It generates an XML like this.

```
<SAPcustom>
  <CustomerQueueMessage>
    <CustomerMaster>
      <CustomerSalesRep>
        <SalesRepTypeCode>1</SalesRepTypeCode>
      </CustomerSalesRep>
      <CustomerAddressType>
        <AddressTypeID>1</AddressTypeID>
      </CustomerAddressType>
      <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
    </CustomerMaster>
    <CustomerQueueMsgID>1</CustomerQueueMsgID>
  </CustomerQueueMessage>
</SAPcustom>
```

Comment: Hi Serkan, thanks for the help. Sorry if I was not clear but what I want is CustomerMaster/CustomerSalesRep and not CustomerMaster/CustomerAddressType/CustomerSalesRep. However, even with your suggestion (define the complete path for each column) I cannot get the structure I want. Actually I cannot use word PATH as it does not allow XMLDATA (it is required for SQL adapter to read the select).

Comment: @user3417479 XMLDATA?  I would not use the at all.  It's for the long deprecated XDR.  Even XMLSCHEMA is not at all required to use the Adapter.  I would focus on getting the output right first, then worry about the Schema.